# Ruby on Rails: multiple file upload with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've implemented a file upload for my users in my ruby on rails app. Each user can upload an xml file, but now I was trying to do it with multiple files, but I'm having some problems. Can anyone give me an example on how can I upgrade my code?

I already can upload multiple files, and I can see them in the DB, but If I upload more (for example 1) he overwrites the previous files. And how can I list all user files?

**EDIT:**

I need to upload only one file at each time (without the multiple: true). **My objective is to add more files after the user uploaded one**.

Comment: Please refer the documentation https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads) excerpt.

> Add a column which can store an array. This could be an array column or a JSON column for example. Your choice depends on what your database supports. For example, create a migration like this:

```
rails g migration add_avatars_to_users avatars:json
rake db:migrate
```

> Open your model file and mount the uploader:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploader
end
```

> Make sure your file input fields are set up as multiple file fields. For example in Rails you'll want to do something like this:

```
<%= form.file_field :avatars, multiple: true %>
```

> Also, make sure your upload controller permits the multiple file upload attribute, pointing to an empty array in a hash. For example:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, {avatars: []})
```

> Now you can select multiple files in the upload dialog (e.g. SHIFT+SELECT), and they will automatically be stored when the record is saved.

```
u = User.new(params[:user])
u.save!
u.avatars[0].url # => '/url/to/file.png'
u.avatars[0].current_path # => 'path/to/file.png'
u.avatars[0].identifier # => 'file.png'
```

Comment: this only works on the new version of mysql. for older version, we need to do it via association

Comment: i did that, but If I need to upload more, It will overwrite the old ones